# How to inject the environment to a service in an Angular multi module project

Tags: angular, angular-injector, angular-environmentproviders

I have an Angular project with 2 apps and 2 libs. I have build a service in one of the libs, because I want to use the service in both apps.

The problem is that I need the `environment` from the `environment.ts` in the service and the that both apps have different environments.

How can I can `inject` the correct environment in the service?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an InjectionToken:

```
const TOKEN = new InjectionToken<YourEnviromentInterface>('env');
```

Then use this token in your service that is used by both apps:

```
@Injectable()
export class TestService {
  #env = inject(TOKEN);

  constructor() {
    console.log(this.#env);
  }

}
```

In the last step you provide a value for this token in both of apps:

App 1:

```
import {yourEnv} from '../somewhere/app1/env.ts'

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [],
  provides: [
    provide: TOKEN,
    useValue: yourEnv
  ]
})
export class App1Module { }
```

App 2:

```
import {yourEnv2} from '../somewhere/app2/env.ts'

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [],
  provides: [
    provide: TOKEN,
    useValue: yourEnv2
  ]
})
export class App2Module { }
```